# Changing the text of the selected option in a React component

Tags: html, reactjs, components

Basically the issue is I have some labels that are too long that they overfill a custom Select component I have and cover the dropdown chevron. The goal is to show a trimmed version of the selected option. And when the user expands the dropdown they should see the options as they were without any trimming.

I put together a simplified attempt and it seems to mostly work except in Firefox.

I am new to React so any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks

```js
function Select({list}) {
  function trimLabel(array) {
    return array.map(entry => {return {value: entry.value, label: entry.label.substring(1, 10)}});
  }
  
  const [ listToRender, updateList ] = React.useState(trimLabel(list));
  const [ currentValue, updateValue] = React.useState();
  
  function onBlur() {
    updateList(trimLabel(list));
  }
  
  function onFocus() {
    updateList(list);
  }
  
  function onChange(event) {
    updateValue(event.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hi</div>
      <select onBlur={onBlur} onFocus={onFocus} onChange={onChange} value={currentValue}>
        {listToRender.map(({value, label}) => <option key={value} value={value}>{label}</option>)}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

const myList = [
  {value: 1, label: "1111111111111111"},
  {value: 2, label: "2222222222222222"},
  {value: 3, label: "3333333333333333"},
  {value: 4, label: "4444444444444444"},
  {value: 5, label: "5555555555555555"},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select list={myList}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I can't notice any difference in firefox, where is the bug?

Comment: Me also didn't see any difference in chrome/firefox/ie

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working now :O It wasn't last night on Windows